# Java Gzip Decompress the string

Tags: java, sockets, gzip

I receive data from server by socket:Normal string concatenation of compressed xml strings.
now: I Can't uncompress the compressed section because result is garbage characters

The packet header is 8 bits of fixed length,Obtain The rest of the data from the socket and copy the compressed data out

```
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    is = socket.getInputStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    is.read(bytes);
    byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,0,1025);
    byte[] endbytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(copy,8,1024);`
```

Decompress using Gzip

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);`
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        GZIPInputStream ungzip = new GZIPInputStream(in);
        int n;
    while ((n = ungzip.read(buffer)) >=0) {
       out.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
    return out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
```

```
Decompress data result:�u��n�0�_攀=4�P��Y1U�PU阀_B7M��H�o�除阀5疣�k�F���i耷iX��
```

How does the client parse data that is a mixture of normal and compressed strings ?

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit]  the question to provide sample input and expected/actual output (probably shown as HEX-encoded bytes not as a garbage string).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, my English is very poor, I will try to change, thanks again.

Comment: Can your code compile? `socket.getInputStream().read(bytes)` should return `int` instead of `byte[]`.

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake because I was trying to shorten the code

Comment: *The packet header is 8 bits of fixed length* - which you're not reading. You should therefore read that one byte and use or discard it, followed by the rest through a zip class to EOT

Comment: *How does the client parse data that is a mixture of normal and compressed strings ?* By following a protocol spec correctly. That would be the case with something like multipart. If there isn't one then it's impossible

Comment: What you are calling "garbage" is binary data. There is no point in printing binary data directly, as you get those question marks in hexagons representing non-printable bytes. First off, never put output like that in a question, since data has been lost and the result is useless. Convert it to hexadecimal or base64, so that it can be converted back to binary by the reader to see what's in the data. Second, your binary data may in fact be perfectly fine. You need to first understand the format of the expected data from information, e.g. documentation, you get from the producer of the data.